# Apache RewriteRule ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I've been practicing with Apaches redirect module and I've come across this a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error all of a sudden, this is baffling me because it's a very simple example. I've seen a lot of posts about this on line but nothing has helped me yet.

My Rewrite rule is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home\.html$ /test/home.html [R]
```

While accessing `localhost/home.html` does rewrite to `localhost/test/home.html` I'm getting the `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Comment: Does changing the flags to `[R,L]` make any difference?

Comment: Thank you arco444, but I'm afraid it doesn't

Comment: Peculiar. Are there any other rules? Is this in a `.htaccess` file? If so where is it located?

Comment: No this is in an Apache config, there is no .rules in the .htaccess file. There is an AliasMatch which maps /test/home.html back to the home.html file

Comment: And what happens if you remove the `AliasMatch`?

Comment: A Not Found error, while the url remains rewritten. If I move the file to a new location the ALiasMatch works, so it would appear the AliasMatch is causing the rewrite rule to be recalled, which is behaviour I wasn't expecting